# Changing HiddenField value with Javascript not changing in C# codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to change a hidden field with javascript and then use that changed value in my codebehind. I have a breakpoint in Page_Load to check if the value of HiddenField1 has changed but it always remains 0 on postback.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var hiddenControl = '<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>';
        var s = $('#cbox');

        $("#cbox").combobox({
            selected: function (event, ui) {
                alert(s.val());
                document.getElementById(hiddenControl).value = s.val();
                alert(document.getElementById(hiddenControl).value);
            }
        });
   });

   <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Value="0" />
```

If I can't get this to work is there any other method to pass information between javascript and c# codebehind ?

Comment: Is it a page lifecycle issue? Is the value updated in Page_PreRender?

Comment: Value is still the default value of 0 in Page_PreRender

Comment: could you post the html that is generated?

Comment: Why did you disable ViewState? Was it causing problems? Or were you just trying everything to prevent the hidden field from being lost?

Comment: Was trying everything to prevent the hidden field from being lost. Thought viewstate might be resetting it to the default value of 0.

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. Can you post more of the code?

Comment: I added a bit more code but its a small piece of a larger project.

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you using? Back when ASP.NET 1.1 was out I had an ASP:Textbox on the page and a popup window for a date picker and it worked great. Along came ASP.NET 2.0 and for what ever reason, if I used JavaScript to modify ANY of the fields the value on the post back would ALWAYS be what the form originaly started as, similar to your situation. Looking back, I never tried to trigger the "change" event, have you? Inside of your selected event try to do $('#' + hiddenControl ).change(); and see if that will cause the post back to carry over the value

Comment: Tried triggering the event and nothing happened. Currently using .Net 4.5

Comment: Could you please update your question with the rendered html instead of the aspx file?  That may help the community address your question.

Comment: See jQuery solution here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77929033/2668852

Answer (score 1):

You may want to note the client side ClientID of you HiddenField and then look at the corresponding value in the Request.Form collection server side during postback.

This way you will check the value sent to the server. 
If the value is correct, the problem might occur because something disturbs ProcessPostData
(manual resetting or dynamic change of form organization for example)

Though it is difficult to give an advice without the whole code, I agree with those saying that EnableViewState=false is surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example on the MS documentation for HiddenField:

```
Form1.HiddenField1.value = s.val();
```

Bottom of this page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx

Comment: Tried that but says Form1 is undefined. Also I don't think it matters since in the question code I'm referencing it by the ID, and searching the document for it.

Comment: form id is form1 but there's a master page involved so might be more nesting ?

Comment: Is there a chance that this field might not even be in form1? Can you test this by setting it to something else on the server (and posting that back)

Answer (score 0):

try to do the same task using html hidden variable

```
 <input id="hdName" runat="server" type="hidden" />
```

As we have provided runat="server" we will be able to access this variable on server side and on hdName.Value we can get the value on server side. Thought it is html control we need to provide hdName.ClientID in javascript as we have given runat=server.

```
document.getElementById('<%= hdName.ClientID %>').value
```

Hopefully this will solve your issue and give you desired result.
Thanks

Comment: Same result as the asp hidden field

Comment: Can you please check the name of control from the page source and share here in here for html hidden field .

Answer (score 0):

Although you can always use set get method to store the values from java script ... 
But here is some simple way to solve it...

case 1 - If control is just for storing purpose ,
      put display : none in it's style and make 
      visible = true in the attribute of the control.

case 2 - if control is to be displayed but in disabled mode put ReadOnly="true" instead of

```
   eg..

    <asp:textbox runat="server" ID="textbox1" Enabled="false"></asp:textbox> will not work

    <asp:textbox runat="server" ID="textbox2" ReadOnly="true"></asp:textbox> will work
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your HiddenField inside the UpdatePanel and use the HiddenField with the ClientID.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to what others said to get a hidden variable/control that can be passed back to the Server Side Code Behind like Button Event or Page_Load, etc. I got the idea from them. But here it is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="hdnErrorMsg" ClientIDMode="Static" style="display: none;" runat="server"/>
```

This can be set in JavaScript, and it will return to Server Side Asp.NET and be used and examined. If you want to preserve it when it goes back to the client, you may have to put it back and all other things that you need. In my case it was an error message. I wanted it to stop in the ASP.NET button click event for the save and exit, but I needed to put the error stuff back so that when it went back to the client it would be there again.